# Which type of storage should I use for my text editor in c?

Tags: c

I am making a Text editor in c for Linux Platform. I am having a confusion whether I can store the text the user types in a memory allocated by `malloc`. Is it safe to allocate huge amount of memory `malloc(10000*sizeof(char))` to store text?

Please help.

Comment: The point is, allocating in stack is problematic as most of the implementations has a very limited stack space. Usually heap is better, but why's need to allocate "huge"..that seems a design bug...10,000 is not huge...anyway.

Comment: That's 10kb of memory. If you aim lower than that, I'm afraid you might limit your userbase.

Comment: Off topic - make sure to write your code so that the size of the buffer is defined by a single constant. In other words - write your code so that you only need to edit one line to change the buffer size.

Comment: On a modern 64-bit operating system you should be able to allocate hundreds of megabytes of memory with `malloc()`. Kilobytes are nothing.

Comment: That said, why are you making a text editor? There are already many good editors and IDEs to choose from.

Comment: I am making a Text editor to improve my programming skills and knowledge.

Answer (score 2):

You can. `malloc()` for 10000 `char` ( only 10k ) is far from "huge".

Answer (score 2):

If you really want to know you should check the return value of malloc:

```
char *buf = malloc(10000);
if(!buf) {
     puts("I couldnt allocate 10K");
}
else {
    puts("allocation successful!");
}
```

Note: should the allocation be successful, you should free it after you are done with it.

Answer (score 0):

there should be no problem allocating much larger buffer in a modern OS,
you may want to consider a separate thread saving the data to the file, thus adding a auto save functionality to your editor.